# Parallel Get Requests - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a directive named as `machineForm` which has a `dataService`

```
dataService.getMachineTaxesById($scope.machineId).then(function (response) {
     $scope.machine.machineTaxes = response.data;
});
```

I'm calling this directive twice at a time.

```
<div class="modal-compare-item">
    <machine-form app-data="appData" 
        index="analyzie_index" 
        machine-id="machineAnalyze.id" 
        machine="machineAnalyze" 
        action="'edit'">
    </machine-form>
</div>
<div class="modal-compare-item">
    <machine-form app-data="appData" 
        index="compare_index" 
        machine-id="machineCompare.id" 
        machine="machineCompare" 
        action="'edit'">
    </machine-form>
</div>
```

The `dataService` for `getMachineTaxesById` is here:

```
// Get Machine Taxes By Id
 this.getMachineTaxesById = function(machine_id) {         
     return $http({
         method: 'GET',
         url: 'https:xyz/api/MachineTaxes/Machine/'+ machine_id,
         headers: {
             'Accept': 'application/json',
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             'Authorization' : $cookies.get('token_type') + " " + $cookies.get('access_token')
         }
     });
 };
```

It works fine if i comment any one of the `<machine-form>` but not when both are called at a time. I get a `response` saying `{"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}`

Is it anything to do with sending parallel request at a time? Should I wait for one request to complete before sending other.

Note : I'm using access token for each request.

Comment: Look in your browser's *Network* console. Find the request that's failing and check the `Authorization` request header. Is it set appropriately? When are those cookie values set (`token_type` and `access_token`)?

Comment: There's no issue from Angulars perspective doing multiple concurrent requests - does your endpoint limit concurrent connections for a particular token, or perhaps are the tokens single use?

Comment: @Brian There are other requests which are successful. Only when I try to hit the same API url multiple times, it responds with `{"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}`

Comment: @DeepakBandi ah ok that eliminates the single use idea - does georgeawg's solution solve the issue? As that would test if it's just multiple simultaneous connections causing the issue. Only other thought I had is perhaps it's rate limited - ie x requests per  second - maybe the API docs (or sometimes the page that you generate your key from) will info on limits or other restrictions

Answer (score 3):

To have the service execute the XHRs sequentially, save the promise from the previous call and chain from it:

```
 app.service("dataService", function($http) {
     var lastPromise;
     // Get Machine Taxes By Id
     this.getMachineTaxesById = function(machine_id) {
         var config = {
                 method: 'GET',
                 url: 'https:xyz/api/MachineTaxes/Machine/'+ machine_id,
                 headers: {
                     'Accept': 'application/json',
                     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                     'Authorization': 
                          $cookies.get('token_type') + " " + $cookies.get('access_token')
                 };
         if (!lastPromise) {         
             lastPromise = $http(config);
         } else {
             lastPromise = lastPromise.catch(function (errorResponse) {
                 //convert rejected promise to success
                 return errorResponse;
             }).then(function(response) {
                 //return httpPromise to chain
                 return $http(config);
             });
         };
         return lastPromise;    
     };
 });
```